# Is it possible to compare two different revisions with VisualSVN plugin in visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, diff, visualsvn

With visualsvn plugin, I am able to compare current working copy with the head revision in the repository.

But how could I compare two different revisions that is not working copy or head revision within Visual Studio?

Comment: What Visual Studio version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it helps:

1. **Visual Studio | VisualSVN | Show Log...**
2. Select revisions to compare, right-click, **Compare revisions**.

Comment: thx, but I'd prefer compare two revisions **within** visual studio.

Comment: You mean the cute internal diff of Visual Studio 2012? File the feature request at http://www.visualsvn.com/support/feedback/?vsvn=

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, I don't think this is possible, *at least not directly*. You would have to do an `SVN Log` *first* and do an `SVN Diff` from there. There is `SVN Blame` but that gives a list of changes per revision on each line instead of the side-by-side diff view.

Comment: You just describe it like there is no option to show diff from Visual Studio at all. This is wrong.

Comment: I suppose you're right - I read the question as "Can I ask VisualSVN to specify the revisions when performing a diff?" I will edit my answer to be more clear.